# Android SQLite database not populating

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, crash

I am trying to create an SQLite database. The create method:

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(CREATE_BASE_TABLE);
    }

}
```

(the constructor and the upgrade function are implemented in that private class as well)

is calling the SQL string:

```
static final String CREATE_BASE_TABLE ="create table if not exists tableData ("
        + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        + "name TEXT,"
        + "image TEXT,"
        + "var1 TEXT,"
        + "var2 TEXT,"
        + ");";
```

but the `execSQL` returns `success=false` , as revealed by the debugger and breakpoints.

In File Explorer I see that `data` is created in the databases folder. I open that file on my local machine and only see a table called `android_metadata` not `tableData` and my fields are nowhere to be seen!

How do I fix it to make my method properly populate my table? Is there a syntax issue with my query?

Comment: Does logcat show any error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very subtle but the error is in your create table command. This line should not have a comma:

```
+ "var2 TEXT,"
```

Instead, it should just be:

```
+ "var2 TEXT"
```

since it is the last column you are defining.

Comment: You do not need semicolons at the end of your statements.